# how to call one webpage from another webpage in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have 2 web applications. webapp1 is running at location say - weblocationlocation1/webapp1/default.aspx
and webapp2 is running at different location say - 
weblocationlocation2/webapp2/default.aspx

Now, If I want to call webapp2/default.aspx from webapp1 then how to call.
how to run Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) of webapp1 from webapp2/default.aspx.

I have to stay on webapp1/default.aspx in my browser. and still want to load webapp2/default.aspx (ONLY from my code of button clicked). in this case, how to store cookie/session variables. and want to maintain them in webapp1 across all pages.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this via a redirect then:

```
Response.Redirect("weblocationlocation2/webapp2/default.aspx");
```

Or directly on the server use

```
Server.Transfer("weblocationlocation2/webapp2/default.aspx");
```

Or

```
Server.Execute("weblocationlocation2/webapp2/default.aspx");
```

The last will return control to the calling method (the second won't).

Comment: Thanks for help Justin,  can i know using above code, session and cookie variables will be maintained. If i want to resend other webpage of webapp2 using cookie/session variables of it, can i do that

Comment: you can use HttpContext class object and store your values in the session such as
public void storeValuesInSession(HttpContext context,Your Variable Object obj1)
{
    context.session.add(your variable name,obj1.value);
}
I think this much is enough.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

as described by @ Justin Harvey you can use Page_load() method and call Response.redirect method to redirect to your desired web page
You can also use javascript if you want to redirect to your page on event such as button on click
for that you can do following

```
btn_demo_onClick()
{
window.location = "abc.aspx";
}
```

it just a complementary option if you want to go with javascript
Thanks

Comment: thanks for your help, may i know, how session/cookie level variable will be maintained using this code., other wise how to store them while redirecting page.

Comment: you can use HttpContext class object and store your values in the session such as public void storeValuesInSession(HttpContext context,Your Variable Object obj1) { context.session.add(your variable name,obj1.value); } I think this much is enough. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Response.Redirect("default.aspx"); // At  URL You will Get the default page as what you are redirecting to.

Server.Transfer("default.aspx"); // At  URL You will not Get the default page as what you are redirecting to.

example : If you are logged in Login page then you want to redirect to default page ,then you can use both the above mentioned methods.